# Javascript Battery API returning Infinite discharging time

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, battery

It is the wish of every smartphone user if it could come true but unfortunatly this doesn't represent reality. Meanwhile... I'm getting that the `battery.dischargingTime` of my android phone is **Inifinite**...! (and I wish it was, but it isn't)

This is my code:

```
if(navigator.getBattery){
    var battery = navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery){
        var level = battery.level;
        var rest = battery.dischargingTime;
    });
}
```

After that, level is 0.94, this is correct, but rest is Infinite. I could understand it didn't work for my desktop computer but on mobile...! I'm using an android with Chrome 43 btw.

**EDIT: I also noticed that in chrome for iPhone this is not even passing the test for the support, despite caniuse not mentioning it: http://caniuse.com/#search=battery**

Comment: is the phone plugged in when you're doing this?

Comment: No, it is unplugged and discharging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This value is `Infinity` if the battery is currently charging rather than discharging, or if the system is unable to report the remaining discharging time.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BatteryManager/dischargingTime

It basically says "sorry, dunno". Ignore that value as invalid and check back again later.

Comment: But I think that my phone is quite standard (android 5) and the browser is modern and up date... I'd expect chrome to be able to report this: http://caniuse.com/#search=battery So, is there any place where I can test this?

Comment: @Vandervals *"After that, level is 0.94, this is correct"* – so it *is* working later on, right?

Comment: it gets the level of battery but it doesn't get the time left

Comment: Sometimes the system simply cannot estimate its discharging time immediately. Try again later.